# Div height solution missing in ie6

Tags: css, html, height

i'm using a empty div to display a line by setting **height 3px**. it works fine in all browsers but in **ie6** the height div displayed with **20px height**. It remains same even for height:0px . But changes in other properties reflects but not height and there is no *duplicate css entry* and *inherited value* from other div. Can any one help please

```
<div id="line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#line {
    border: none;
    background-color: #134c7c;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any empty space inside the div?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internet Explorer has the odd idea that the content of every element should be at least one character high. You can get around this by using the overflow attribute, that way the content can remain a character high, but it doesn't affect the height of the element itself:

```
.line { height: 3px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: +1 had a similar problem and your solution helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: Yet another IE bug. Absolutely essential to know for any web developer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
line-height:0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess.

Inspect whether there is any space inside the element. If yes then set the

```
font-size: 1px;
```

property of the element.

Answer (score 0):

try with space in the div or  
Just guess