# height does not work in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tried to create a cross at the center of the body with a red background, screenshot:

[image]

This is the html fragments:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        .mask{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        .mask .row{
            position:absolute;
            left:50%;
            width:40px;
            margin-left:-20px;

            top:50%;
        }
        .mask .col{
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            height:40px;
            margin-top:-20px;

            left:50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="row" style="height: 2px; margin-top: -1px; background: red;"></div>
        <div class="col" style="width: 2px; margin-left: -1px; background: red;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it worked as expected in IE7+,FF, chrome. Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/3f2RE/

However the `div` have an unexpected height in IE6, screenshot:

[image]

I do not know what's going on? Any way to fix it?

Comment: IE6 ? too bad... less than 5% use that.

Comment: [Try using `overflow: hidden` on the div.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588302/div-height-solution-missing-in-ie6)

Comment: still supporting IE6 ?

Comment: Try giving border-top instead of background color.

Comment: The IE6 support is optional, but it would be better if it can work.

Comment: @Marty is absolute right, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

so `overflow: hidden` solver your problem, so its commenter's task to paste comment as answer. Or askers should do this, so other visiters will know that this question has a right answer.

Comment: Actually what I *should* have done is marked the question as a duplicate of the one I linked to in my comment.

Comment: But we can't see in questions list that this question has solved. At least you should mark the question as duplicate. So the word Duplicate will be shown after question title in questions list.